# Open-source git-based CMS to integrate with our software platform in Django

Tags: open-source, cms, git, crm, django

**The problem:**

We are 6 developers writing a CRM software in Python/Django. In our database, we have hundreds of email templates. They are sent to our users in different situations (states of their accounts, basically). The content team changes those templates, and other related ones (private area messages for our clients) A LOT. We want to keep track of those changes without affecting the development of CRM itself.

Right now, we are working with Django fixtures. So, after each change, we need to dump the content of the email table to a json file (the fixture) and push that content to the git repository. Big pain.

**The constraints:**

- Of course, the content must be accessible programmatically at any moment. So, if I need to send an email to a client, I just pull out the right email from database (or wherever it is stored...), build a mail message and send it to the email queue.
- We want to roll back to any previous state of any email at any moment (simple plain text tracking)

**Proposal:**

A **git-based CMS** sounds like a good solution. But we're open to anything

Answer (score 0):

**FrontAid CMS** might be what you are looking for. It is a hosted [CMS for JSON files in Git](https://frontaid.io/). You can define a data model using JSON that describes those email templates. Based on the model, FrontAid then generates the forms that can be filled with content. The content is then stored directly in a JSON file in your own Git repository. That seems to be exactly what you are doing manually :) Note that this currently only works with GitHub repos but the integration of other providers is on the roadmap.

Disclaimer: I work at FrontAid. Please feel free to get in touch if you have any questions or suggestions. You can find our email address here: https://frontaid.io/docs/

Comment: Looks like this can't be self-hosted and only works with GitHub no self hosted Git either?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes that is correct. I updated the answer to reflect that. Self-hosted Git is a tricky one as there is no way to read and write single files quickly and in a scalable way.